# eccentrcity of vertices in the given graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I was calculating eccentrcity of vertices of the following generalized Petersen graph $P(15,2)$.

[image]

For the vertx $u_0$, vertices $u_6$ and $u_7$ are farthest at a distance 4 and for the vertex $v_0$ farthest vertex is $v_7$ at a distance 6.
And thus  $e(u_0) = 5$ and  $e(v_0) = 6$. Is my calculation right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $e(u_0)=5$ and $e(v_0)=6$. Also, for $0\le i\le 14$, since there is an isomorphism that maps $u_0$ onto $u_i$ and an isomorphism that maps $v_0$ onto $v_i$, then $e(u_i)=5$ and $e(v_i)=6.$